# TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Tags: python, excepciones

tengo el siguiente código y no me deja ejecutarlo, alguien me puede ayudar?
El código es medio largo pero el error esta en la linea 130, donde están las funciones.
me tira el siguiente error = TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
Intente buscar pero no encuentro manera de solucionarlo, la verdad no entiendo por que no se ejecuta

```
def Calcular1():
    try:
        _db = float(db.get())
    except ValueError():
        _db = 0
    try:
        _sd = float(sd.get())
    except ValueError():
        _sd = 0
    try:
        _ds = float(ds.get())
    except ValueError():
        _ds = 0
    try:
        _p = (_sd * _ds ** 2)/(2 * _db **2 - 2 * _ds ** 2)
    except ZeroDivisionError():
        _p = 0
    pl.insert(_p)

p = ttk.Button(f1, text="Calcular", command= Calcular1())
p.grid(column=2, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Podrias indicar que linea es la 130 en ese codigo

Comment: except ValueError():
  _p3 = 0

Comment: No es `except ValueError():`, es `except ValueError:` except espera el tipo (AKA clase) no una instancia. Lo mismo para el resto.

Comment: Gracias! Ahora el problema que tengo es que no me agrega el resultado a la lista, que puede ser?

Comment: _p es un resultado float() que necesita insertarse en pl, que es un ListBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las excepciones no son instancias, por lo que no deben llevar ().

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
def Calcular1():
    try:
        _db = float(db.get())
    except ValueError:
        _db = 0
    try:
        _sd = float(sd.get())
    except ValueError:
        _sd = 0
    try:
        _ds = float(ds.get())
    except ValueError:
        _ds = 0
    try:
        _p = (_sd * _ds ** 2)/(2 * _db **2 - 2 * _ds ** 2)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        _p = 0
    pl.insert(_p)

p = ttk.Button(f1, text="Calcular", command= Calcular1())
p.grid(column=2, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Si! Funciono, ahora mi siguiente problema es que en las listas no me aparece el resultado de _p, le doy click a calcular y no se actualiza

Comment: has probado con pl.insert(0, _p)  ?

Comment: si, también probe eliminando todos los elementos de la lista, y luego insertar _p, y siempre queda en 0, nunca cambia

Answer (score 0):

Tienes tres errores apreciables en tu código, el primero, el que causa la excepción, se debe a que la cláusula `except` espera la siguiente sintaxis:

```
"except" [expresion ["as" identificador]] ":
```

dónde expresión es una **clase** que derive de `BaseException`. Tu no usas una referencia a la clase, sino que usas un objeto de la clase, ya que al usar paréntesis la estás instanciando. Por lo tanto, en vez de:

```
except ValueError():
                 ^^
                 ^^
```

debe ser:

```
except ValueError:
```

Por otro lado, comentes un error muy similar con lo que le pasas al argumento `command`. Dicho argumento espera una referencia a la función (realmente un callable cualquiera) que será llamada cuando el botón se pulse, tu en cambio ejecutas las fucnión (de nuevo los paréntesis tras el nombre), por lo que le pasas su retorno, que es `None`.

Esto hace que cuando pulsas el botón no ocurra nada, la función se ejecutó cuando el intérprete ejecutó el módulo, antes de que la ventana siquiera fuera creada y le paso a `command` `None`... Por lo tanto, en vez de:

```
p = ttk.Button(f1, text="Calcular", command= Calcular1())
                                                      ^^
                                                      ^^
```

debe ser:

```
p = ttk.Button(f1, text="Calcular", command= Calcular1)
```

Por último, no se si `pl` es una lista de Python o un widget `ListBox`, sea como sea el método `insert` está siendo usado mal. En ambos casos debes pasar el índice dónde insertar como primer argumento y el valor como segundo:

**Lista Python**

- Insertar al inicio:

  ```
  pl.insert(0, _p)
  ```
- Insertar al final

  ```
  pl.append(_p)
  ```

**tkinter.ListBox**:

- Insertar al inicio:

  ```
  pl.insert(0, _p)
  ```
- Insertar al final:

  ```
  pl.insert(tkinter.END, _p) / pl.insert("end", _p)
  ```

Por tanto, el código debería quedar:

```
def Calcular1():
    try:
        _db = float(db.get())
    except ValueError:
        _db = 0
    try:
        _sd = float(sd.get())
    except ValueError:
        _sd = 0
    try:
        _ds = float(ds.get())
    except ValueError:
        _ds = 0
    try:
        _p = (_sd * _ds ** 2)/(2 * _db **2 - 2 * _ds ** 2)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        _p = 0
    pl.insert("end", _p)

p = ttk.Button(f1, text="Calcular", command=Calcular1)
p.grid(column=2, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias! funciono!